# Postgres slave caused master to go into a bad state

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, master-slave, postgresql-9.5

I'm running a postgres 9.5.2 master/slave streaming repl cluster on separate ubuntu EC2 instances inside docker containers with WAL-E streaming to an S3 bucket from the master node. The slaves are synchronous. One synchronous slave was on an EC2 instance that ran out of disk space today (there are other services/docker containers running on that box). This caused that slave to stop working and go into a bad state naturally. By the time I realized it was down the master had deleted the the wal segments that particular slave needed to catch up. So for the time being a I shut down the docker container that the slave was running on. I didn't think to check on the master because a slave going down shouldn't cause any issues with the master. But it seems to have caused some type of issue. Here is the only error I'm seeing in the logs

```
WARNING:  canceling the wait for synchronous replication and terminating connection due to administrator command
DETAIL:  The transaction has already committed locally, but might not have been replicated to the standby.
FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
```

WAL and Replication conf. everything else is sys default

```
wal_level = hot_standby
checkpoint_timeout = 10min
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env /usr/local/bin/wal-e wal-push %p'
archive_timeout = 60
max_wal_senders = 5
wal_keep_segments = 8
hot_standby = on
```

This caused the master have new connections hang and then wouldn't kill the connections. They would just languish until all the connections were used.

Does anyone know why when a slave leaves the cluster the master would go into a bad state like this? That doesn't seem right. I would think a slave should have 0 impact on the master being able to perform its job. If the slave goes bad or drops from the cluster the master shouldn't care and keep on doing what it's doing. Why would this happen?

Comment: can you post your replication settings

Comment: i've added the postgresql.conf replication settings i have.

Comment: You are using a third party package for archive. I can only presume that this is some problem caused by that

Comment: The third party app is WAL-E it's not used in replication and only sends the wal's to my S3 bucket. The archive command itself is just telling wal-e here is where the archive files are and push a copy to an s3 bucket. How would that effect replication? Also, I've removed node from this cluster before and this never happened.

Comment: *because a slave going down shouldn't cause any issues with the master. But it seems to have caused some type of issue*. Well, you're using *synchronous* replication, so the master will wait until at least one replica has confirmed replay. Clear `synchronous_standby_names` on the master or remove the problem replica from it.

Comment: @CraigRinger so as long as one synchronous slave is up the master will stay in a good state? Even if one is down? Or do all synchronous slaves have to be in a good state?

Comment: One should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Answer used that was provided by @CraigRinger